# Gradle 3.0 transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug duplicate entry

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've googled and searched in here the solution for this but haven't found it. I just updated my Android Studio to 3.0 and I'm trying to port my app to use feature modules in order to be able to make an Instant App, but when I try to run the app from Android Studio, I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$FileCreatorException: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

I tried to exclude such file using packagingOptions, but apparently is not working. Here are my build.gradle files:

**Project build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26

    supportLib = '26.1.0'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

**App module build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/avocarrot-android-builds/dist" }
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.myapp.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 23004003
        versionName "4.0.0.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    } 


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }
}

dependencies {
    def mopub = '4.16.0@aar'
    def avocarrot = '4.6.0'
    def exoplayer = 'r2.2.0'
    def mobfox = '3.2.3'
    def pubnative = '2.0.4'
    def facebook = '4.+'
    def pubnativeFacebookAdapter = '2.0.2-4.22.1'
    def taboola = '1.3.1'
    def okhttp = '3.8.1'
    def okio = '1.13.0'
    def picasso = '2.5.2'
    def firebase = '11.4.0'
    def playServices = '11.4.0'
    def supportLib = '26.1.0'
    def gson = '2.8.1'
    def circleimageview = '2.1.0'
    def floatingactionbutton = '1.3.0'
    def mpAndroidChart = 'v3.0.2'
    def gridViewHeaderFooter = '1.0.12'
    def multidex = '1.0.1'
    def floatingsearchview = '2.0.3'
    def cropper = '1.0.1@aar'
    def adapterdelegates = '3.0.1'
    def rxjava = '2.x.y'
    def rxandroid = '2.0.1'
    def rxjavaAdapter = '2.3.0'
    def retrofit = '2.3.0'
    def rxbinding = '2.0.0'
    def diagonallayout = '1.0.6'
    def fabSpeedDial = '1.0.6'
    def butterknife = '8.7.0'
    def sqlbrite = '2.0.0'
    def leakcanary = '1.5.1'
    def debugDB = '1.0.1'
    def crashlytics = '2.6.8@aar'

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/admarvel-android-sdk-core-adcolony.jar')
    implementation files('libs/libAdapterSDKMoPub.jar')
    implementation files('libs/AdMobMediationAdapter.jar')
    implementation files('libs/lsmsdkadmobmediationadapter.jar')
    implementation files('libs/MobFox-Android-AdMob-Adapter.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gcm.jar')
    implementation files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/comscore.jar')
    implementation files('libs/hmediaLib-1.3.0.jar')
    implementation(name:'adux-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation "com.avocarrot.sdk:mediation-sdk-nativead:$avocarrot"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:$exoplayer"
    implementation "com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:$facebook"
    implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:$facebook"
    implementation "com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:$facebook"
    implementation "com.github.mobfox:MobFox-Android-SDK-Core:$mobfox"
    implementation "net.pubnative:sdk:$pubnative"
    implementation "net.pubnative:sdk.adapter.facebook:$pubnativeFacebookAdapter"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp"
    implementation "com.squareup.okio:okio:$okio"
    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$picasso"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLib"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLib"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLib"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLib"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$rootProject.supportLib"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$playServices"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$playServices"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:$playServices"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson"
    implementation "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:$circleimageview"
    implementation "com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:$floatingactionbutton"
    implementation "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:$mpAndroidChart"
    implementation "in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:$gridViewHeaderFooter"
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:$multidex"
    implementation "com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:$floatingsearchview"
    implementation "com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:$cropper"
    implementation "com.hannesdorfmann:adapterdelegates3:$adapterdelegates"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxjava"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxandroid"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$rxjavaAdapter"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:$rxbinding"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-support-v4:$rxbinding"
    implementation "com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:$diagonallayout"
    implementation "io.github.yavski:fab-speed-dial:$fabSpeedDial"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebase"
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterknife"
    implementation "com.squareup.sqlbrite2:sqlbrite:$sqlbrite"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterknife"
    debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:$leakcanary"
    releaseImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$leakcanary"
    testImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$leakcanary"
    debugImplementation "com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:$debugDB"

implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$crashlytics") 
    {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation(name: 'DebugSettings', ext: 'aar')

    wearApp project(':wear')
    implementation project(':myapp-base')
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Base module build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    baseFeature true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLib"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

//    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    application project(':app')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're including the libs directory twice in your app's build.gradle

```
// Once
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
// And once more, but more verbose
implementation files('libs/admarvel-android-sdk-core-adcolony.jar')
implementation files('libs/libAdapterSDKMoPub.jar')
implementation files('libs/AdMobMediationAdapter.jar')
implementation files('libs/lsmsdkadmobmediationadapter.jar')
implementation files('libs/MobFox-Android-AdMob-Adapter.jar')
implementation files('libs/gcm.jar')
implementation files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/comscore.jar')
implementation files('libs/hmediaLib-1.3.0.jar')
```

This could be where your issue originates. Decide on one way to include these and let me know whether that works.